How to pass lib_dirs into action script?
As a result of building my C++ libraries with GN I would like to generate .props file to use it in C++/CLI project.
I'm trying to pass all the necessary properties to a script within an action:
action("generate_props") {
  script = "generate_props.py"
  outputs = [ "$target_gen_dir/my_libraries.props" ]
  args = [
    "{{include_dirs}}",   # works
    "{{defines}}",        # works
    "{{libs}}",           # Error: Unknown substitution pattern
    "{{lib_dirs}}"        # Error: Unknown substitution pattern
  ]
  
  deps = [
    ":LibraryA",
    ":LibraryB",
  ]    
}

It works well for include_dirs and defines, but it doesn't for libs and lib_dirs.
Any help is appreciated.
